# Work Details View Show User with Days Off

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

When viewing the Sprint Backlog board and Work Details, is there a way (possibly via extension?) to mark a given user differently to show they are actually marked as Off for the given day?

From my screenshot, the bottom user is out for this whole week, but you don't really know that until clicking over to the Capacity tab to view days off.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that there are no supported extensions from Microsoft doc at present.
You may submit a suggestion at website below:

[feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest?space=21)

**UPDATE**

You can use `Capacities-Get` REST API to get user's daysOff information. And you can build by yourself. Please Refer to doc: [Capacities-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/capacities/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#teammembercapacityidentityref)

Comment: thanks! would i be able to build my own via the devops APIs? any suggestions around that?

Comment: of course you can. See details in updated answer.